# Please remove the installation medium

Tags: boot

My problem is:
During installation everything goes fine up to the moment when it asks me: **Please remove the installation medium and push ENTER button**. After doing it, and restart - the computer turns on Windows 10 not Ubuntu. During rebooting I can push F12 button but it shows me information that there is only Windows 10. I tried to install it with or without WI-FI (both option the same result). I've tried as well to do go through the problem to run Ubuntu without installation and then to install it from the file that is there but it finishis always the same.
Computer: Acer Helios 500.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the output of "efibootmgr" from ubuntu live